# Regex with mixed character set and different counts for each

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a number with a fixed length with a regex. The Problem is, that in some cases the number is split into portions devided by spaces or dashes. Examples are:

- 123456789
- 123 456 789
- 12 34567 89
- 123-456-789
- 12-345678-9

I think you get what I mean. The Regex I'm currently using would only get the first number:

```
(?<=^|\D)([0-9]{9})(?=$|\D)
```

When I add spaces and dashes to my character list like this:

```
(?<=^|\D)([0-9 -]{9})(?=$|\D)
```

I still don't get the desired results, as the "numbers" containing them are longer than 9 characters. If I take more characters I would end up with a lot of false results.

What I would need is a way to tell the regex to take numbers, spaces and dashes but with the following restrictions:

- The number can only be 9 characters long (without spaces and dashes)
- no two spaces or dashes or a mix of them should be in a row

Additionally it would be nice if the dashes and spaces wouldn't be returned, but thats not that important

Comment: Try [`(?<!\d)\d(?:[ -]?\d){8}(?!\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/gflCjt/1). Are you extracting the matches from a larger text?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That looks pretty good. I'm extracting them from a freetext. Anything could be in there. I'll play around a bit with your regex and try to fully understand it. If you create an answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
(?<!\d)\d(?:[ -]?\d){8}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%5Cd%28%3F%3A%5B%20-%5D%3F%5Cd%29%7B8%7D%28%3F!%5Cd%29&i=123456789%0D%0A123%20456%20789%0D%0A12%2034567%2089%0D%0A123-456-789%0D%0A12-345678-9%0D%0A-123456789%0D%0A%0D%0A12-%203423456&o=e). To only match ASCII digits, pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to the regex constructor.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit symbol immediately to the left of the current location (same as `(?<=^|\D)`)  (*NOTE*: to avoid matching `234.123 4567-89` replace this lookbehind with `(?<!\d\.?)`)
- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:[ -]?\d){8}` -  exactly 8 occurrences of a space or `-` and then any digit
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location (*NOTE*: to prevent matching `123456789.34`, use `(?!\.?\d)` instead).

C# usage to extract matches:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\d)\d(?:[ -]?\d){8}(?!\d)", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I added alternatives for the lookarounds just in case you need to fine tune the extraction pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This regex works:

```
(\d\s?-?){9}
```

It's looking for 9 groups of any digit followed by optional whitespace and optional hyphen character.

So it would match all of your examples, but would also match the following:

- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
- 1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6 -7 -8 -9 -
- etc.

It's a simple regex, but it might not meet your requirements if you want to exclude matches with a trailing space or hyphen. [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew)'s answer provides a more complex regex which may suite your needs more thoroughly.